# Is it possible to pass dynamic data from a parent dynamic block to descendant dynamic block via context?

Tags: block-editor

I know that in WordPress it is possible to create dynamic blocks in PHP which can, among other things, gather data from external APIs to collect data needed to render them. I also know it is possible to use context to pass attribute values from parent blocks to their descendants. However, is it possible to store data retrieved in a dynamic custom block's render callback from an external API and pass that down to a descendant block?

Basically, I have a custom parent block, `parent`, which makes a call to an external API in PHP to get some data during the execution of its render callback function. `parent` will have multiple child custom blocks, (`child-1`, `child-2`, etc.) that will need to receive and render parts of the data gathered from the API call made in `parent`.

So far, I have tried to achieve this by setting attributes on `parent` and using `providesContext` and `usesContext` to get this data, and then storing the relevant data from the API call in `parent`'s attributes during the execution of `parent`'s render callback.

e.g.
parent block.json excerpt:

```json
  "attributes": {
    "example_attr": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": ""
    }
  },
  "providesContext": {
    "abc/example_attr": "example_attr"
  },
```

child block.json excerpt:

```json
  "usesContext": [
    "abc/example_attr"
  ]
```

parent block render callback excerpt:

```php
function abc_render_block_content_wrapper( $attributes, $content, $block ) {
  // Some code omitted to zero in on the important bits
  $raw_data = get_cons_data(); // Successfully calls external API and gets constituent data

  if ( $raw_data ) {
    $attributes['example_attr'] = $raw_data['example_attr']; // Set the attribute value based on what I get from the external API
  }
}
```

child block render callback excerpt:

```php
function abc_render_block_bio_info( $attributes, $content, $block ) {
  // Some code omitted to zero in on the important bits
  $attr = $block->context['abc/example_attr'];
  // This is empty string, i.e. the default value, even though the attribute in the `parent` block gets successfully overwritten upon completion of the API call
}
```

Unfortunately, the child blocks never receive the updated attribute values; they only see the initial/default attribute values.

Is there any way to do what I am attempting to do? I take it that context may not be the right tool for this (unless I'm just not using it properly), but is there some other way to get data from a parent block to one of its descendants?

Comment: what you're trying to do is theoretically possible and how the query loop block works with post title/etc. I would note though, that making a HTTP request to get data and provide it like that is a massive performance hit, it's important to separate retrieving/storing the data from a remote source, and displaying it, so that they don't happen in the same request. Perhaps by fetching the data in cron and caching it for a short period, or doing it on publish/save/update/etc